# Add button in Angular Material Table filter

Tags: angular-material2

I **have** a Table Filter in Angular Material :-

[image]

I **want** an icon at the right side of this filter, like below :-

[image]

I have tried with many configurations, without luck.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    <span class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn" (click)="doSomething()">
          <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What part of this are you struggling with exactly? is this what you are trying to do - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgbf9o ?

Comment: @Und3rTow, Thanks. I need exactly the same. Can we do it without writing css?

Comment: yes, you can handle the layout using [angular-flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), then you won't need to use CSS

Comment: Thanks again. I will go through this.

Comment: Working like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Material 2 supports that in their documentation

```
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value"/>
  <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

https://stackblitz.com/angular/eyrxeklkoyq?file=app%2Finput-clearable-example.ts

Comment: This is adding a button inside the field itself. But, there is not any space between "Filter Line" and "Icon", as I have indicated in the image (what I want).
@Und3rTow solution is working as per my requirement.
>>
Still it might be a good solution, if I do not want space. As it doesn't require flex.